# Dojo Datagrid with editable DateTextBox get inconsistent default value

Tags: datagrid, dojo, date-format

I have a datagrid with a column of type date. It is editable using dijit's DateTextBox. The problem is when it gets instantiated, it takes the value as actual value -1day.

I have a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gVbS8/9/).

I can only get the date in this format "yyyy-MM-dd".

Here is the structure for the column with date:

```
{
  name:'Start Date', field:'startdate', 
  editable:true, relWidth: 100,
  type: dojox.grid.cells.DateTextBox,
  constraint:{datePattern:'yyyy-MM-dd', selector:'date', locale: 'en-us'},
  formatter:function (d) {
     if(typeof(d) === "string"){
        d = dojo.date.stamp.fromISOString(d)
      }
      return dojo.date.locale.format(d, this.constraint)
   }
 }
```